# pass array as argument to script module in ansible

Tags: scripting, ansible

I am using a script module to run a script on some hosts. I have an array ansible variable, that I want to pass the script as space separated arguments. Passing the array variable directly as argument does not help. Suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

You can join your list with [jinja filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#id7) and pass it as a variable, like this:

`ansible -m script -a "myscript.sh {{ test_list|join(' ') }}" localhost -e "{"test_list": [1,2,3]}"`

If myscript.sh is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Args are: ${@}, 1st: $1 2nd: $2, 3d: $3
```

The output will be:

```
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": true,
    "failed": false,
    "rc": 0,
    "stderr": "",
    "stdout": "Args are: 1 2 3, 1st: 1 2nd: 2, 3d: 3\n",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "Args are: 1 2 3, 1st: 1 2nd: 2, 3d: 3"
    ]
}
```